# installing i8kutils stops loud fan noise

Tags: 14.04, dell, fan

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop on a Dell 5521 laptop. When I install i8kutils, fan noise stops suddenly without doing any configuration. When I check with `i8kfan` command, output is `-1 0`. When I want to change configuration with the `i8kfan` command (for example I run `i8kfan -1 1`), after a second later it changes to `-1 0` again. Is this situation normal?

Comment: 2023. Installing i8kutils saved my life!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem with this tutorial;
https://www.keenformatics.com/how-to-solve-dell-laptops-fan-issues-in-ubuntu/